# Google Sheets, Time command to display stock market times open/close

Tags: google-sheets, time

I am trying to display "Market opens in "X" hours, minutes" and market closes in "x" hours, minutes.

The stock market is open 0930-1630 and im trying to do a simple script that will show that, but I keep getting an #error.

```
=if(TIME(HOUR(<,09:30)), value_if_true, "Market Close in:", value_if_true, "Market Opens in:")
```

Comment: Please show your script.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You need to get the current time, compare it to the range of times the markets are open, and display a different result based on the whether the market is open or how long it is until the market opens.*

#### Formula:

```
=IF(time(hour(now()),minute(now()),second(now()))<TIME(9,30,0),"Market opens in " &HOUR(TIME(9,30,0) - time(hour(now()),minute(now()),second(now())))& "hours, "&MINUTE(TIME(9,30,0) - time(hour(now()),minute(now()),second(now())))&" minutes.",IF(time(hour(now()),minute(now()),second(now()))>=TIME(16,30,0), if(minute(now()) > 30,"Market opens in " &HOUR(TIME(23,59,59) - (time(hour(now()),minute(now()),second(now()))))+9& " hours, "&MINUTE(TIME(23,59,0) - time(hour(now()),minute(now()),second(now())))+31&" minutes.","Market opens in " &HOUR(TIME(23,59,59) - (time(hour(now()),minute(now()),second(now()))))+10& " hours, "&MINUTE(TIME(23,59,0) - time(hour(now()),minute(now()),second(now())))-29&" minutes."),"Market Open"))
```

#### References:

- [Google Sheets function list - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)